# MVC in android populating listview from resources

Tags: android, xml, listview

It seems their should be a way to statically populate a listview with an array of buttons using only xml using android:resource or android:entries possibly. I would prefer a resource xml file seperate from my main layout. If I understand MVC the view is more of a static thing where as the controller has listeners for the view and makes changes to the view. I don't know if string array can hold button objects or where I am going wrong. Any suggestions? Oh and the buttons all should have the same properties but maybe that is another question?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/MainFrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
package="com.union.doogie"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewmain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@buttons/Buttons" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   </TextView>
 </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android allows that you define ID of user interface components dynamically in the layout files, via the @+id/your_id notation.

To control your IDs you can also create a file called ids.xml in your /res/values folder and define all IDs in this file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <item name="button1" type="id"/>
 </resources>
```

This allow you to use the ID directly in your layout file.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listViewmain"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@id/button1" >

<TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</TextView>
</ListView>
```